# How do I merge multiple SVN repositories and keep one Branches and Tags folder

Tags: svn, merge, repository

I have been asked to combine multiple (several hundred) svn repositories into a single repository.  (Management decision)

I need to import the full revision history, BUT instead of having multiple trees of Trunk, Branches, Tags, I need a single Trunk, Branches and tags folder at the top level.  Each existing repository would become a folder under those folders.

Management wants the full history to be imported.  (If possible, they'd like the old revision number to be stored as an attribute)

Has anyone done this?  Is there a tool to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a tool, but you can copy the trunks of each projects to the appropriate folder in the trunk of the combined project (same with branches and tags).  If noone else suggests a better approach, you can write a script to do the discovery of folders using the command-line version of svn (e.g. use a linux machine or cygwin to achieve this on Windows).

Comment: I ended up writing a quick program to dump each existing repository.  Then it loads the dump data into the new repository.  Finally it moves any Branches or Tags folders to the main repository Branches/Tags folders.  Your answer got me on the right thought path to accomplish this.